# tf.exe errors out with MSB3073: exited with code 1 while doing a label /recursive - diagnostic advice?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I'm working with a VS 2008 project file as the build script... when it gets to:
TF.exe label Build_01_29_1$/RootDirectory/ChildDirectory . /recursive
It errors out right away (no time out issues that I could fined)
All I get is that is "exited with code 1" and error:MSB3073 and nothing else descriptive.

So any advice on how to diagnosis this further? Or anybody run into it before?

Comment: Looks to me like your missing a space between _1 & $/ `TF.exe label Build_01_29_1 $/RootDirectory/ChildDirectory . /recursive`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the path to TF.exe is right? MSB3073 seems to be related to MSBUILD not being able to find stuff.

Comment: is TF.exe in a post-build event? (I'm asking because of this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/6b832027-0829-42de-9e6b-d5187e78cd20)

Comment: Sadly no... pre-build. TF.exe is being used at this stage to re-label everything each build with the current version number. This is being done because in the final product it checks if there are newer 'modules' and downloads them based on version number. - Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Path in the Environment Variables and try once again.

Setting the Path:

Computer->System properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->Select the Path -> Edit it.